# Inherit from DbSet<TEntity> in Entity Framework Code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would like to ask, if is possible to create classCollection that inherit from DbSet and use this collection in DbContext. I use Entity framework - Code first.

I have simple class Student:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then I try to create custom StudentCollection, where I can define custom methods:

```
public class StudentCollection : DbSet<Student>
{
    public void CustomAdd(Student student) { /*...*/ }
    public bool Exists(Student student) { return true; }

}
```

Finally I would like to use StudentCollection according to which EF create table in database.

```
public class ModelContext : DbContext
{
  //typical use: Works ok
  public virtual DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

  //Dreamed use: Generate error, EntityType 'StudentCollection' has no key defined.
  public virtual StudentCollection ExtendedStudents { get; set; }
}
```

At the end I would like to write:

```
Db.ExtendedStudents.CustomAdd(newStudent);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are you doing that you need a class derived from `DbSet`? There may be other ways to reach the same end goal.

Comment: Have you considered using a extension method on `DbSet<Student>`? For `CustomAdd(Student student)` you should really override `DbContext.SaveChanges()`

Comment: I tried to implement custom collection to which I can delegate responsibility for table collection. I know it's possible to use [Repository and Unit of work](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).
What I tried to do is something similar to `teacher.Students.CustomAdd(newStudent)` 
`public class Teacher
    {
        public virtual StudentCollection Students { get; set; }
    }`